# Is there a way to get 'live' output lines from a python script spawned by child_process.execFile without flushing stdout every time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, child-process

I am trying to get the lines a ('never ending') python script puts into stdout. But currently my code would only log something to the console when the python process exits. Is there a way I can get the 'live' output of the python script line by line?

spawn_child.js:

```
let execFile = require("child_process").execFile;

var child = execFile("python3", ["PATH_TO_FILE"]);

child.stdout.on("data", data=>{
    console.log(data.toString());
});
child.stderr.on("data", data=>{
    console.log(data.toString());
});
child.on("exit", code=>{
    console.log("Child exited with code "+code);
});
```

The python file:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(3)
    print("test")
```

Edit: It works when using a nodejs script instead of a python script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change python script to

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("test")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and increase the buffer size of the child process

```
const child = execFile("python", ["./runner.py"], {
    detached: true,
    maxBuffer: 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
});
```

or you can do it without the flushing to stdout with [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

```
const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');

let pyshell = new PythonShell('runner.py');
    
pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});

pyshell.end(function (err, code, signal) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
    console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
    console.log('finished');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there actually no way to do that without flushing stdout every time?

Comment: yes you can do it with python-shell i update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use [spawn](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of execFile, dont forget options `shell` and `stdio`.

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const child = spawn("python3", ["file.py"], {shell: true, stdio: 'inherit'});

child.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
  
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('Child process exited with exit code '+code);
});
```

You can also add `cwd` option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That seems to have the same result. The stdout data event will only fire after the python process ends.

Comment: You probably miss shell and stdio options, I edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to implement something similar inside a NextJS application and wanted live output from my python script and using `python-shell` had the same issue that it was only giving me output when the process existed and I ended up using `node-pty` instead which worked as expected:

```
import { spawn } from "node-pty"
const pyProcess = spawn("python", ["path/to/python/script"], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: 80,
    rows: 30,
    cwd: process.cwd(),
  });

pyProcess.on('data', function (data: { toString: () => any; }) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

pyProcess.on('exit', (code: any) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
```